# Bootstrap ScrollSpy: Hide the vertical navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 Bootstrap columns, a menu column is on the left, a container column is in middle and another column on the right.  When I scroll down a middle column, menu items will be highlight by using Bootstrap ScrollSpy.

In order to get the scroll spy works, I have to set `overflow: auto;` for the middle column.  Without this property, the scroll spy won't work!

Problem: Because of `overflow: auto;`, it shows a vertical navigation bar in the middle column.  That doesn't look good.  I've tried to set some different properties, but it didn't work.

How to hide the vertical navigation bar in the middle column?

Please give a hand.  Thanks

Sample in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ysnjoa8/)

CSS

```
.scrollspy-example {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
#spy {
  position: fixed;
}
.right-side {
  background: gray;
  height: 120px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div  id="spy">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#scroll1">First Section</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#scroll2">Second Section</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#scroll3">Third Section</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#scroll4">Fourth Section</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 scrollspy-example" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#spy">
  <div id="scroll1">
    <h2>First Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll2">
    <h2>Second Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll3">
    <h2>Third Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="scroll4">
    <h2>Fourth Section</h2>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
    <p>
    During Compile time, the compiler converts the source code into Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL). Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) are CPU-Independent set of instructions that can be effectively converted to the native code. Now with the help of JIT compiler, IL code can be executed on any computer architecture supported by the JIT compiler.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="right-side">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't see a verticle nav bar in your fiddle. Also don't see it when reusing your code. Can you provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, it was a wrong URL!  Just updated my question.  Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/6ysnjoa8/   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css (I'm not sure if this works in all browsers though).

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L5kp4cde/

---

Comment: Hi shaoe2020, Thank you so much!  is `::-webkit-scrollbar` working for cross browsers?

Comment: It doesn't work in firefox I think, and possibly doesn't work in edge. You may still need a solution for those. There are jquery scrollbar plugins that you might google and check out.